# Logstash terminates when I add host in elasticsearch as output parameter

Tags: cmd, logstash, elastic-stack

**command line** :

```
logstash.bat -e 'input{stdin{}} output{elasticsearch{host=>localhost}}'
```

but when i dont use localhost in the command line , I am able to run it successfully and the elastic search engine also receives it.

**Command line:**

```
logstash.bat -e 'input{stdin{}} output{elasticsearch{}}'
```

**elastic search cmd window:**

```
[Doctor Doom] added {[logstash-WIP-441006063-7740-12126][w7GRC1TuT-ixdrokWmQYlg][computername][inet[/10.95.226.40:9301]]{data=false, client=true},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(join from node[[logstash-computername-7740-12126][w7GRC1TuT-ixdrokWmQYlg][computername][inet[/10.95.226.40:9301]]{data=false, client=true}])
```

Your help is greatly appreciated. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`.

When you do not specify `localhost` it runs because the default value of `host` is 127.0.0.1 and not localhost.

So, your command should be.

```
logstash.bat -e 'input{stdin{}} output{elasticsearch{host=>["127.0.0.1"]}}'
```